# Is it possible to embed a GIF in an RTF file?

Tags: embedded, gif, rtf

I write a lot of tutorials using RTF as the format, but would like to be able to insert animated GIFs into them. I am wondering if this is possible with some code of any kind? I tried to drag and drop a GIF into the RTF but it only shows one frame.

If this is not possible, is there another file format that I could use that would include rich text editing with the possibility to add animated GIFs?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to embed a GIF in an RTF file?

Yes.

> I am wondering if this is possible with some code of any kind?

Based on some minor research, certain programs (e.g. Word) may require some sort of weird workaround to display animated GIFs, but this doesn't seem to be strictly necessary depending on the software you use.

> I tried to drag and drop a GIF into the RTF but it only shows one frame.

Certain programs will embed only the first frame of the animated GIF (e.g. Wordpad) rather than the entire GIF and some program will not play an animated GIF, even though the full animated GIF is properly embedded by that program (e.g. Word).

**Possible Solution**

Currently, [Apache OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/) (and its offshoot, [LibreOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/)) will both properly (fully) embed and play animated GIFs in RTF documents.

> Is there another file format that I could use that would include rich text editing with the possibility to add animated GIFs?

As noted, the problems you are encountering are more likely due to software. For instance, switching to an [OpenDocument Text (`.odt`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) format reveals the same issues in Wordpad and Word (i.e. only the first frame of an animated GIF is embedded or there is no playback for properly embedded GIFs).